# An Error Was Encountered Unable to load the requested file: $content.php

Tags: codeigniter

hi  im new with codeigniter, i need to view home.php after login but no luck , there is CI error message :

An Error Was Encountered  Unable to load the requested file: $content.php

fyi, there is 2 file inside home.php (v_sidebar.php , v_isi.php )

application/controller/home.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

class Home extends CI_Controller {

```
public function index()
{
    $isi['content'] ='v_isi';
    $this->load->view('v_home',$isi);
}
```

}

application/view/v_home.php

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <!-- PAGE CONTENT BEGINS -->

                    <?php echo $this->load->view('$content');?>

                            <!-- PAGE CONTENT ENDS -->
                        </div><!-- /.col -->
                    </div><!-- /.row -->
                </div><!-- /.page-content -->
```

and of course the file called v_isi.php exist 
application/view/v_isi.php

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-success">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i>
                                </button>

                                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-check green"></i>

                                Welcome to
                                <strong class="green">
                                    Ace
                                    <small>(v1.3.3)</small>
                                </strong>,
the lightweight, feature-rich and easy to use admin template.
                            </div>
```

but after succes with login page , the file v_isi.php couldnt load even the file exist.

need some help here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change :

```
<?php echo $this->load->view('$content');?>
```

to

```
<?php $this->load->view($content);?>  // removed echo & quotes
```

and you're done.